# Julia LatexStrings plotting text subscripts

Tags: matplotlib, plot, julia, latex

I am using `PyPlot` to plot things in Julia. I want my plot label to use LateX fonts so I'm using `LatexStrings`.

I would like to write a variable with subscript such that the subscript is not written in italics, i.e in Latex: $z_{\text{eff}}$.

The closest I can get with `LatexStrings` is `L"z_{eff}"` however the subscript is written in italics in that case.

Is what I am looking for possible with these packages (I don't want to switch to something other than `PyPlot`)?

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
L"z_{\mathrm{eff}}"
```

if you don't mind using `\mathrm` instead of `\text` to make the subscript be upright and non-italic.

`L"z_{\text{eff}}"` works in `LaTeXStrings` by itself, but sending that on to `PyPlot` messes something up. Things like `\mathtt` and `\rm` also work, but `\textnormal` and `\textrm` don't.

Comment: This is the answer, but I'll note that `\textrm` works for me.